# How do I create a printable report in Kiwi TCMS?

Tags: kiwi-tcms

I want to create a printable report of a test run in Kiwi TCMS version 9.0.1. However I cannot find any way to accomplish this. Can someone explain how to get this done?

According to https://kiwitcms.org/blog/kiwi-tcms-team/2019/03/03/legacy-reports-become-telemetry/ this feature should be available.

> Feature: Printable Test Execution Report
>
> As a tester I want to have a nice looking TestRun execution report which I can present to my >managers, stakeholders and/or customers. The page needs to be printer friendly for “Print to >PDF” or print on paper!
>
> **Kiwi TCMS already has this feature.** Clicking the [Report] button ...

It seems that the report button has been removed in favor of the telemetry button though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However I cannot find any way to accomplish this.

Just try printing the TestRun page. It looks good in its new design and that's why there's no separate page which rearranges the data in a printer-friendly way. The current layout should be printer friendly as it is.

If there's something missing/not quite right that's an improvement request which should go into GitHub Issues.

Answer (score 0):

Digging through the patch notes, I have found that this feature was removed in Kiwi TCMS version 6.6, see https://github.com/kiwitcms/Kiwi/blob/master/CHANGELOG.rst#kiwi-tcms-66-19-mar-2019

> Remove legacy reports.

and https://github.com/kiwitcms/Kiwi/issues/657

> We are planning to remove the existing reports feature because they are not well designed and the code internally is a huge blob that can't be extended very easily. Kiwi TCMS team would like to reimplement existing functionality that folks find useful, add new types of reports (incl. nicer graphics and UI) and make it possible for the reporting sub-system to be more easily extendable.

So I guess the blog entry is a bit misleading and it is currently not possible to create printable reports using Kiwi TCMS version 9.0.1, save for writing a private plugin that adds this functionality.